# how to get all excel sheet data in c# using OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx

My excel sheet contains sheet1, sheet2, sheet3(total 3 sheets). i need to get all data from 3 sheets.
This is my code given below

```
           var cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;'");

            var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr);

            // get schema, then data
            var dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                var schemaTable = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                //DataTable dtCols = cnn.GetSchema("Columns");
                if (schemaTable.Rows.Count < worksheetNumber) throw new ArgumentException("The worksheet number provided cannot be found in the spreadsheet");
                string worksheet = schemaTable.Rows[worksheetNumber - 1]["table_name"].ToString().Replace("'", "");
                string sql = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", worksheet);
                var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // ???
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                // free resources
                cnn.Close();
            }
```

From the above code, i gets data from sheet 1 only. how can i get data from all sheets?

Comment: I think you may be missing some of the code. Where does `worksheetNumber` come from? You basically need to loop through the worksheets, but you are looking for a specific single sheet each time. Need more code to help further I am afraid

Answer (score 0):

you must declare worksheetNumber before

> if (schemaTable.Rows.Count < worksheetNumber) throw new ArgumentException("The worksheet number provided cannot be found in the spreadsheet");

like this

> int worksheetNumber = 3;
> if (schemaTable.Rows.Count < worksheetNumber) throw new ArgumentException("The worksheet number provided cannot be found in the spreadsheet");

Comment: hai, my requirement changed. it may be n number of sheets. may be 10 orr 15 or 20. how to get these data?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < schemaTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                 
                    string worksheet = schemaTable.Rows[i]["table_name"].ToString().Replace("'", "");
                    string sql = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", worksheet);
                    var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
                   
                   

                }

Comment: i have modified with the above code. gets sheet & data. but where to store each data into single variable?

Comment: read each data from data table after new OleDbDataAdapter

> da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
> cnn.open();
> DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
> da.Fill(myTable);
> foreach(DataRow myRow in myTable.Rows)
> {
>     string col1 = Convert.ToString(myRow[0]); // read first column
> }